# Playframework routes question

Tags: java, forms, action, playframework

I have this in my applcation routes file:

```
GET    /new                 Tweets.create
POST   /new                 Tweets.save
```

And in my view I'm creating a form like this:

```
#{form @save()}
...
#{/form}
```

But once is submit the form it's sending me to  `/tweets/save` and not to `/new`. Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Show your entire routes file, not just the snippet in question. As Codemwnci mentioned, the order in which you define your routes matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already tried the route below (which is the correct way to use routes)

```
#{form @Tweets.save()}
```

and this did not work, I think you may have put your route  in the wrong place. Make sure it is at the top of the routes file, and not after the catch-all route. The routes file is processed in order, so if the catch-all is found, this is used first and your other route is ignored. The catch-all looks like

```
*   /{controller}/{action}     {controller}.{action}
```

Comment: This was causing the problem, I didn't know the order mattered and I placed my code at the bottom of my routes file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
 #{form @Tweets.save()}
```

I think it is suggested to use class names with method names.

**EDIT:**

The way the play framework routing works is you define some route as

```
GET     /clients         Clients.index
```

If a request encountered with URI `/clients` then it will be intercepted to `Clients.index()`. If you have another routing such that

```
GET     /clients         Clients.save
```

Then the framework ignores this routing because `/clients` aready has a mapping. (Most probably it is giving some error in the console or logging stream, check your logs.)

Therefore you can't make it work like that. I see, you request a reverse mapping that will return the same URI for different methods. However the framework aims to intercept requests so that it will simply ignore your second routing.

Try to separate pages. Most probably what you want is to render the same views for two functions. You can do that without redirecting them to the same URI.

Comment: Can you use 'show source' option on your browser and tell us what is `action` attribute of `<form>` element?

Comment: The form tag generated is `<form action="/tweets/save" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" >`

Comment: Well I think I have figured out the problem. Check the answer again, please.

Comment: The problem was with the order in which routes were.. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think (if I did not misread) that the issue is you expecting the wrong behavior.

As I understand you expect that the submit will go to Tweet.save() (POST method) and then back to Tweet.create() (GET method) as both share the same path (/new).

In reality Play is calling Tweet.save() and it expects a render at the end of Tweet.save() to display some result. If you want to redirect to Tweet.create() you can do a call to that method at the end of the implementation of Tweet.save(), with either:

```
create(<params>);
```

or

```
render("@create", <params>);
```

and that should redirect (via 302) to the GET version.

Comment: I was expecting a behaviour as described here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/guide9 The problem was the order of my routes.